# Virtual Machine Manager 2008 R2 Workgroup Licensing Question

Tags: virtualization, scvmm

Can I have more than one Virtual Machine Manager 2008 R2 Workgroup License on a single domain, or would I need to move to the Enterprise Licensing?

Right now we have 3 physical host machines, but potentially could add a few more over the next year or so, but not sure on that exact number.

I am aware that I would have to manage the 2 sets of 5 physical boxes separately on different consoles and machines, but the cost savings would justify that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running through the install, it looks like it's trusted based, so there is no technical restrictions here, just legal.